# EL Expression Unbalanced jsf

Tags: html, css, jsf

I have this weird problem,I am trying to read the width of a div using expression language, the div is in a datatable here is a sample

`<h:dataTable value="#{MyBean.List}" var="bean" id="active-list">                <div class="green-div" style="width: #{bean.ratio}px"></div>
</h:dataTable>`

but when I run the page here is what happen`<h:dataTable value="#{MyBean.List}" var="bean" id="active-list">                                                 <div class="green-div" style="width: #{bean.ratio"></div>
</h:dataTable>`

And I get the "EL Expression Unbalanced" exception, I want to know why the "}" and the "px" disappears. thanks in advance

Also here is my web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<display-name>MyAPP</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/login.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/errorPage.html</location>
</error-page>
<session-config><!-- Session timeout is set to 30 Mins -->
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<filter>
    <filter-name>Extensions Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Extensions Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

Comment: what does "run the page" mean?

Comment: I mean when I deploy the application and open the page on a brwser

Comment: If you see facelets code when you run the page this means you've got a problem with your FacesServlet configuration. Please post your web.xml file, and tell us more about your environment (container, jsf version ..etc)

Comment: No I don't see any facelets code , I am using weblogic , jsf2

Comment: You DO see facelets code on your browser (`<h:dataTable .../>`). This means your FacesServlet configuration is wrong. Are you getting any errors while starting/deploying your application?

Comment: This code is what I am developing itself not what I get as source code what I get as source code is pure html

Comment: Ok I got the answer : remove the hash sign "#" make it dolar sign "$".

    <div style="width: ${bean.ratio} px"/>

Answer (score 0):

Try width this

```
<h:dataTable value="#{MyBean.List}" var="bean" id="active-list">
    <div class="green-div" style="#{'width: '.concat(bean.ratio).concat('px')}"></div>
</h:dataTable>
```